# How would I join several pieces of thick plywood together?

Tags: wood, woodworking, plywood, joinery

Ok so this question is regarding my Design and Technology GCSE, I have 5 pieces of 15mm thick plywood. These pieces of plywood have no middle and need to join together to make a sort of box with another piece of plywood that is 3mm thick on the bottom. I was thinking about just using wood glue to glue every piece together or would it be more durable if I drilled holes, through all the pieces, countersunk at the top and used screws instead or is there another way entirely for example biscuit joints.I'm limited to, while it is still very well equipped, a school workshop.

Comment: If you are just "sandwiching" plywood together, glue. If you are truly constructing a box, glue **and** screw.

Comment: How big is this box going to be?  How strong does it have to be?

Comment: The box is to contain the electronics for a speaker, so a circuit board, a heat sink and some wiring and 2 speakers. The box itself, with all the layers joined, is 280 by 200 by 75 mm. The box doesn't have to be durable but I want to look at all my options when it comes to joining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glue and clamp to laminate the plywood together. Just be careful to make sure all the pieces are all well aligned and clamped evenly - use additional wood top and bottom to spread the clamping force evenly and avoid damaging the plywood. Also be mindful that the glue will be squeezed out of the joints so will need to be carefully cleaned off before it dries.

Comment: when properly clamped, wood glue joints can be stronger than the wood. For the application noted, this is the easiest method.